# How do I get Laravel assets to work in production, works fine in dev?

Tags: laravel

I have a header blade:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

When i load my page on the prod server, i see this in page source:

```
<link href="public/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

On my dev server, I was getting:

```
<link href="https://myserver.com/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This worked fine in dev, but on prod, I am getting 404 on the custom.css file.

Even if i enter the url:

```
https://myserver.com/css/custom.css
```

I get a 404.

some possibly releveant env settings:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=https://myserver.com
```

Some logs from dev:

```
[23/Jun/2022:01:16:23 -0400] "GET /css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 200 528 "https://myserver.com/" 
[23/Jun/2022:01:16:23 -0400] "GET /js/myJs.js HTTP/1.1" 200 162 "https://myserver.com/" 
[23/Jun/2022:01:16:23 -0400] "GET /css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 200 205348 "https://myserver.com/"
```

from prod:

```
[23/Jun/2022:01:15:17 -0400] "GET /css/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404 
[23/Jun/2022:01:15:17 -0400] "GET /css/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404
[23/Jun/2022:01:15:17 -0400] "GET /js/myJs.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Answer (score 0):

apache vhost config was not correct:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secreport/public/index.php
```

should be:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/secreport/public
```

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css')}}" type="text/css">
```